Azure Monitor alert condition for VM availability
I set up a logic app to turn off and turn on my virtual machine automatically outside of business hours. This causes me to receive email notifications every day from Azure monitor if the VM availability changes. Is there a way for me to still receive these email alerts if the machine's availability changes during business hours, but not receive them due to the daily shutdown and power-on process?

Not able to find any logic or condition to finetune the alert rule

Do you need an alert if the VM is turned off or on during business hours, or if the VM is stopped or started at any time?

You can monitor VM availability status by checking heartbeat data every 5 minutes within specified hours. If the machine is not available, you will receive an alert. Query result"

Sorry, I cannot comment on this at the moment.
You are getting alerts due to status becomes 0 when the VM shuts down within VM. This is according to Microsoft documentation in this link.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/monitor-vm-reference.
If you use a different approach to schedule the daily shutdown of the VM not within the VM. Possibly using Azure Portal > VM > Operations > Auto Shutdown, Then the metric value should become null and your current alert will not trigger because your current alert condiotion is set to trigger when the value less than 1 and hopefully it will not trigger for null. Consequently no alert is sent. This is the desired outcome.



Note: The VM availability metric helps in detecting if the machine is unavailable, in which case you will receive an alert.


You can check the VM availability status by using heartbeat on every 5 minutes within a specified time
(Bussiness hours) period. If the machine is not available for more than 5 minutes, you will receive an alert.
Here is a KQL query to check the VM availability status within the specified time period.
// Define the time range as per your requirement to trigger the alert

let startOfDay = startofday(now());
let startOfBusinessHours = startOfDay + 3h; 
let endOfBusinessHours = startOfDay + 6h; 


let LastHeartbeatDuringBusinessHours = Heartbeat
| where ResourceType == "virtualMachines"
| where TimeGenerated between (startOfBusinessHours .. endOfBusinessHours)
| summarize LastHeartbeat = max(TimeGenerated) by ResourceId, Computer, OSType;


Heartbeat
| where ResourceType == "virtualMachines"
| join kind=inner (
    LastHeartbeatDuringBusinessHours
) on ResourceId
| where TimeGenerated == LastHeartbeat
| where LastHeartbeat < now() - 5m // Check if the last heartbeat is older than 5 minutes
| project LastHeartbeat, ResourceId, Computer, OSType

Output

Here is the KQL query to trigger an alert if the VM is deallocated or started within a specified time period. For more details, follow the Stack link provided by Ivan Glasenberg.
AzureActivity 
| where OperationName in ("Deallocate Virtual Machine","Start Virtual Machine")
| where TimeGenerated between (startOfBusinessHours .. endOfBusinessHours)
| project TimeGenerated,OperationName


Follow the Stack Link  and Stack link2 answered by me to create an alert using KQL query
